# How to extract intents of dynamic broadcasts

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I am using a dynamic broadcast receiver to receive a broadcast from a separate class that is sending a list as its intent. The problem is that the intent, upon reception, is null. Is this a consequence of the type of intent filter i used?

**broadcast origin**

```
  private void sendToUI(List tweets) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("tweet_result"); //tweet_result is a string to identify this intent
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList("data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) tweets);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

**broadcast receiver**

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            List<tweet> tweets = (List<tweet>) intent.getExtras().get("data");

            if (tweets == null) {
                tweets_results.setText("No tweets");
                return;
            } else {
                for (tweet tweet : tweets) {
                    String content = "";
                    content += "Created at: " + tweet.getCreated_at() + "\n";
                    content += "Text: " + tweet.getText() + "\n";
                    content += "Retweets: " + tweet.getRetweet_count() + "\n";
                    content += "Favs: " + tweet.getFavorite_count() + "\n\n";
                    tweets_results.append(content);
                }
            }
        }
    };
   @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to fix few things.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction("tweet_result");
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);


}

private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        List<tweet> tweets = (List<tweet>)
     intent.getParcelableArrayList("data");

        if (tweets == null) {
            tweets_results.setText("No tweets");
            return;
        } else {
            for (tweet tweet : tweets) {
                String content = "";
                content += "Created at: " + tweet.getCreated_at() + "\n";
                content += "Text: " + tweet.getText() + "\n";
                content += "Retweets: " + tweet.getRetweet_count() + "\n";
                content += "Favs: " + tweet.getFavorite_count() + "\n\n";
                tweets_results.append(content);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: after making this change `List<tweet> tweets = (List<tweet>)
     intent.getParcelableArrayList("data");` i get the error `cannot resolve method getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.string)`. Do you think it should be `List<tweet> tweets = (List<tweet>)intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");` ? That being said, when i made tried my above suggestion, i got a separate error `cannot cast 'java.util.ArrayList<android.os.Parcelable>' to 'java.util.List<com.example.package.tweet>'`

Comment: ` intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<tweet>("data")`; try like this

Comment: ok after making slight alteration, this has worked. `List<tweet> tweets = new ArrayList();
            tweets =  intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");`